# How do I use recursion to loop my code (when user enters invalid input, it prompts them again)?

Tags: c++

So I wrote this code in C++ format and I am trying to loop the code as to when the user enters an invalid input when prompted to enter a number between 1 and 10 it doesn't just terminate if invalid input, but asks the user to enter a valid input until correct a valid input is entered. New to c++ so I'd appreciate the help

```
#include <iostream>
#include <cstdlib>
#include <ctime>
#include <cctype>

using namespace std;

//constants go here
const int MIN = 1;
const int MAX = 10;

const char YES = 'Y';
const char NO = 'N';

//Booleans go here
char wantToPlay();
bool getIntValue(int &userValue);
bool play(int userValue);

//Main routine
int main(){

printf("Welcome, this program will guess a number between 1 and 10");
printf(", if the program guesses the number correctly you'll get VICTORY ROYALE");
printf(", if you don't get it right you'll get BETTER LUCK NEXT TIME, Good luck :)\n");

char playOrNot = wantToPlay();

  //If user value is TRUE, program outputs "Victory Royale" and terminates
  //If user value is FALSE, program outputs "Better luck next time" and terminates
  //If user value is NOT VALID, program outputs "Not a good number" and prompts user again
  //If user enters "N" when prompted to answer Y or N
  int input = -1;
  switch (playOrNot){
  case YES:
    if(getIntValue(input)){
      srand (time(NULL));
      if(play(input)){
    cout << "Victory Royale!"<<endl;
    }else{
    cout<<"Better Luck Next Time!"<<endl;
    }
    }else{
      cout<<"not a good number\n";
    }
    break;
  case NO:
    cout << "sorry you hate my game\n";
    break;

  default:
    cout << "that was not valid\n";
    //If user enters value that is completely not valid
  }


  return 0;
}
char wantToPlay(){
  //Prompt user to enter Y for yes and N for no
  char answer = NO;
  cout << "Do you Want to Play? 'y'for" << " yes, 'n' for no" << endl;
  cin >> answer;
  answer = toupper(answer);
  return answer;
}


bool getIntValue(int &userValue){
  //Prompt user to enter a number between the Min(1) and Max(10)
  bool valid = false;
  cout <<"Enter a number between " << MIN << " and " << MAX <<endl;
  cin>>userValue;
  if(userValue >= MIN && userValue <= MAX){
    valid = true;
  }


  return valid;
}
bool play(int userValue){
  //Random tool to give a random between 1 and 10
  bool match = false;
  int random = (rand()%10)+1;
  if(userValue==random){
    match=true;
  }
  return match;
}
```

Comment: Just put a loop in your main before the input and include the switch {}. In the NO case  add return 0;

Comment: Daniel, the best thing you can do is get an IDE with a debugger and learn how to debug & answer questions like this for yourself.

Comment: I recommend Visual Studio if you have access to a PC. It has one of the best debuggers available. To understand how to debug requires you to spend 30 or so minutes to read some documentation. Make sure you learn how to single step through code and how to add a breakpoint.

Comment: *"How do I use recursion to loop..."* You don't. You use loop iteration with proper validation.  Recursion always falls into the Single Responsibility Principle bucket : Just because you can, doesn't mean you should.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
#include<iostream>
using namespace std;
int main()
{
    char s;
    cout<<"Enter valid number between 1 to 10"<<endl;
    cin>>s;
    while(!((s>='1') && (s<='10')))
    {
        cout<<"The number you have entered is not in range 1 - 10"<<endl;
        cout<<"Enter an valid number I.e. between 1 to 10"<<endl;
        cin>>s;
    }
    cout<<"You have successfully entered an valid number"<<endl;
    return;
 }
```